# Python SQLAlchemy create_Engine error "Connection time out"

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I have read quite a few posts around this but couldn't find a resolution. I am able to read from Postgres but getting a connection time out error when I use create_engine string. I know the credentials are correct because I can read from PostGres.

My aim is to write dataframe (df) to postgres directly from Python and going forward keep appending the rows to that table. I have changed the password and the IP address in the example below. Not sure if this is relevant but I am using Tunnel in Putty to connect to remote server and launch Jupyter notebook and then trying to write to Postgres DB.

My code

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2 
import io
password    = 'Pas@$tk$@a' #This is just an example. MY password has special characters

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://admin:password@1.12.11.1:5432/DEV_Sach_D', connect_args={'sslmode':'require'}, echo=True).connect() # I have changed the IP here for security reasons
conn = engine.connect()
df.to_sql('py_stg_test', con=conn, if_exists='replace',index=False)





Error I get 

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   3211         try:
-> 3212             return fn()
   3213         except dialect.dbapi.Error as e:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in connect(self)
    306         """
--> 307         return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
    308 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in _checkout(cls, pool, threadconns, fairy)
    766         if not fairy:
--> 767             fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
    768 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in checkout(cls, pool)
    424     def checkout(cls, pool):
--> 425         rec = pool._do_get()
    426         try:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py in _do_get(self)
    145                 with util.safe_reraise():
--> 146                     self._dec_overflow()
    147         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py in __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     71                     exc_value,
---> 72                     with_traceback=exc_tb,
     73                 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    206         try:
--> 207             raise exception
    208         finally:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py in _do_get(self)
    142             try:
--> 143                 return self._create_connection()
    144             except:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in _create_connection(self)
    252 
--> 253         return _ConnectionRecord(self)
    254 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __init__(self, pool, connect)
    367         if connect:
--> 368             self.__connect()
    369         self.finalize_callback = deque()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __connect(self)
    610             with util.safe_reraise():
--> 611                 pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
    612         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py in __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     71                     exc_value,
---> 72                     with_traceback=exc_tb,
     73                 )

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    206         try:
--> 207             raise exception
    208         finally:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __connect(self)
    604             self.starttime = time.time()
--> 605             connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
    606             pool.logger.debug("Created new connection %r", connection)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py in connect(connection_record)
    577                         return connection
--> 578             return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    579 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in connect(self, *cargs, **cparams)
    583         # inherits the docstring from interfaces.Dialect.connect
--> 584         return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    585 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    121     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 122     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    123     if cursor_factory is not None:

OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "1.12.11.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-28cdb6a0c387> in <module>()
      4 password    = Pas@$tk$@a'
      5 
----> 6 engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://libertypassageadminuser@libertypassage:password@1.12.11.1:5432/Dev_Sach_D, connect_args={'sslmode':'require'}, echo=True).connect()
      7 conn = engine.connect()
      8 df.to_sql('py_stg_test', con=conn, if_exists='replace',index=False)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in connect(self, close_with_result)
   3164         """
   3165 
-> 3166         return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
   3167 
   3168     @util.deprecated(

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in __init__(self, engine, connection, close_with_result, _branch_from, _execution_options, _dispatch, _has_events, _allow_revalidate)
     94                 connection
     95                 if connection is not None
---> 96                 else engine.raw_connection()
     97             )
     98 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in raw_connection(self, _connection)
   3243 
   3244         """
-> 3245         return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
   3246 
   3247 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   3214             if connection is None:
   3215                 Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
-> 3216                     e, dialect, self
   3217                 )
   3218             else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(cls, e, dialect, engine)
   2068         elif should_wrap:
   2069             util.raise_(
-> 2070                 sqlalchemy_exception, with_traceback=exc_info[2], from_=e
   2071             )
   2072         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    205 
    206         try:
--> 207             raise exception
    208         finally:
    209             # credit to

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py in _wrap_pool_connect(self, fn, connection)
   3210         dialect = self.dialect
   3211         try:
-> 3212             return fn()
   3213         except dialect.dbapi.Error as e:
   3214             if connection is None:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in connect(self)
    305 
    306         """
--> 307         return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
    308 
    309     def _return_conn(self, record):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in _checkout(cls, pool, threadconns, fairy)
    765     def _checkout(cls, pool, threadconns=None, fairy=None):
    766         if not fairy:
--> 767             fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
    768 
    769             fairy._pool = pool

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in checkout(cls, pool)
    423     @classmethod
    424     def checkout(cls, pool):
--> 425         rec = pool._do_get()
    426         try:
    427             dbapi_connection = rec.get_connection()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py in _do_get(self)
    144             except:
    145                 with util.safe_reraise():
--> 146                     self._dec_overflow()
    147         else:
    148             return self._do_get()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py in __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     70                 compat.raise_(
     71                     exc_value,
---> 72                     with_traceback=exc_tb,
     73                 )
     74         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    205 
    206         try:
--> 207             raise exception
    208         finally:
    209             # credit to

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py in _do_get(self)
    141         if self._inc_overflow():
    142             try:
--> 143                 return self._create_connection()
    144             except:
    145                 with util.safe_reraise():

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in _create_connection(self)
    251         """Called by subclasses to create a new ConnectionRecord."""
    252 
--> 253         return _ConnectionRecord(self)
    254 
    255     def _invalidate(self, connection, exception=None, _checkin=True):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __init__(self, pool, connect)
    366         self.__pool = pool
    367         if connect:
--> 368             self.__connect()
    369         self.finalize_callback = deque()
    370 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __connect(self)
    609         except Exception as e:
    610             with util.safe_reraise():
--> 611                 pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
    612         else:
    613             # in SQLAlchemy 1.4 the first_connect event is not used by

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py in __exit__(self, type_, value, traceback)
     70                 compat.raise_(
     71                     exc_value,
---> 72                     with_traceback=exc_tb,
     73                 )
     74         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py in raise_(***failed resolving arguments***)
    205 
    206         try:
--> 207             raise exception
    208         finally:
    209             # credit to

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py in __connect(self)
    603         try:
    604             self.starttime = time.time()
--> 605             connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
    606             pool.logger.debug("Created new connection %r", connection)
    607             self.connection = connection

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py in connect(connection_record)
    576                     if connection is not None:
    577                         return connection
--> 578             return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    579 
    580         creator = pop_kwarg("creator", connect)

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py in connect(self, *cargs, **cparams)
    582     def connect(self, *cargs, **cparams):
    583         # inherits the docstring from interfaces.Dialect.connect
--> 584         return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
    585 
    586     def create_connect_args(self, url):

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in connect(dsn, connection_factory, cursor_factory, **kwargs)
    120 
    121     dsn = _ext.make_dsn(dsn, **kwargs)
--> 122     conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    123     if cursor_factory is not None:
    124         conn.cursor_factory = cursor_factory

OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "1.12.11.1" and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Comment: Have you got the right privileges to “write” into your db ?

Comment: You say you can read from the database.  The first step of reading from the database is connecting to it.  How do you do that?  Different program/language? Different IP?  Different user?

Comment: Is your database connection supposed to go through the tunnel?  Or just the connection you use to launch the program which established the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Very silly of me. I was using the wrong IP in the string. Instead of using POSTGRES DB name I was using the IP of the machine itself.

Thanks to all who answered.